# a 'Pending Error message While executing Script in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am getting this kind of response in command prompt after executing the script.  I have added steps for the scenario in step def still what more code i have to add.

```
Given(/^i am on Gmail Homepage $/) do
  Pending# write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
When(/^enter blank details for login $/) do
  Pending# write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
Then(/^show error message $/) do
  Pending# write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this kind of response from Cucumber when your step definitions are not an exact match for the steps. Double check that these Regexps match the steps in your Gherkin file(s). I'd guess that the trailing space is your issue, though.

```
Then(/^show error message $/) do
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the sentence upper/lower case to make sure it is exactly the same with step-definition.

I found the same issue and resolve it by changing "T" to "t".